# Cannot mirror repo from gitlab to github

Tags: git, github, gitlab, mirror

## The error

```
push to mirror: git push: exit status 128, stderr: &quot;remote: No anonymous write access.\nfatal: Authentication failed
```

This is the error gitlab has for me when trying to update a mirror.

## The mirror

So i have a repo on gitlab that i want to mirror to github but it just doesn't want to work.
The url i use is just the url of the repo. I generated an access token with almost all permissons that have to do with repos but i still get this error.

Comment: "Access token" for GitLab or GitHub? If you can push to other GitHub repo's I would think it's an issue with GitLab auth specifically. More error output + info on how mirror was set up would be useful.

Comment: @JBallin i have a repo on gitlab and i want to mirror it to github so i generated a github access token enabling almost all things but it still does not work also there is no more error output apart from the repo that i was trying to mirror to. The mirror is setup trough Repo > Settings > Repository > Mirror > mirror direction is push and auth is password the url is https://github.com/username/repo the password i enter is the github access token.

Comment: It seems like the issue is that GitHub doesn't have the right credentials to push to GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer PULL to mirror accounts from github (or other source) to gitlab. The Pull option is only available for [GitLab Premium](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/). (Check the image or click the link to the post)

[image]

**[Workaround:](https://dev.to/sgolovine/how-to-backup-your-github-code-to-gitlab-35nl)**

Assuming your github repository is called "foo", and assuming you already have the same repository created in gitlab, go to your local github repository:

```
cd foo
# only one time
git remote add backup https://gitlab.com/myuser/foo
# run backup
git push -u backup master
```

will ask for the gitlab username and password (or token)

And that's it.

PD: to avoid:

```
error: push failed for some references to 'https://gitlab.com/myuser/myrepo'
help: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrates remote changes (ie 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
help: See 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for more details
```

replace `u` with `f`:

```
# run backup
git push -f backup master
```

**Optional:**

You can use the following script from now on to update your repo on github and backup on gitlab:

```
chmod +x foo_update.sh
./foo_update.sh
```

with content:

```
#!/bin/bash
# date
now="$(date +'%m/%d/%Y')"
while true; do
    read -p "Do you want to update-backup your repo? (y/n)" answer
        case $answer in
          [Yy]* )
        # execute command yes
    cd foo
    git add .
    git commit -m "Update $now" # Modify it according to your needs 
    git push -f origin master
    git push -f backup master
    cd -
    echo OK
        break;;
          [Nn]* )
        # execute command no
            break;;
        * ) echo; echo "Please answer YES (y) or NO (n).";;
    esac
done
```